# is it possible to override Gradle publish task to excute bootJar task instead?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

Multi-module Java API project using spring boot gradle plugin

Following works and produces jar that is executable.

```
./gradlew build bootJar
```

I can run it using command

```
java -jar api.jar
```

But the build pipeline can only execute

```
./graldew publish (unable modify task to bootJar due to the build template being a custom one)
```

which results in an error

```
no main manifest attribute in api.jar
```

Here is bootJar task

```
bootJar {
    mainClass = 'com.my-company.api-main-class'
}
```

Question is
is it possible to modify build.gradle and override publish task so that when publish task is executed, it actually runs bootJar task instead?

Comment: You can use `publish.dependsOn bootJar` but you also have to put `publish.dependsOn bootJar` in your task.